# Split with conditional in tag group determinator

Tags: r, split

I would like to split my `df` based in `tag` column. However, just the first row for each tag group has a flag. All other rows have `NA` value. All groups are in the interval between the flags. In this representative example the group `Seg_1` includes rows with `NAME`== `Prb1`, `Prb2` and `Prb3`. The `Seq_2` includes `Prb4` and `Prb5`. The `Seq_3` includes just `Prb6` and `Seq_4` just `Prb7`.

My `df`:

```
df <- "NAME Position tag
       Prb1   20      Seg_1 
       Prb2   30      NA
       Prb3   40      NA
       Prb4   100     Seg_2
       Prb5   200     NA
       Prb6   300     Seg_3
       Prb7   400     Seg_4"

df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `library(zoo) ; df <- na.locf(df); split(df, df$tag)`?

Comment: Yes, worked prefectly well! Thank you!

Comment: You can also try in `base` R: `split(df,cumsum(!is.na(df$tag)))`